# ruby on rails I18 loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I would like to know if it's possible to make a loop for each I18 sub-item.
Assume I have a .yml file like the following:

```
subject:
    item1:
       title:
       text:
    item2:
       title:
       text:
    item3:
       title:
       text:
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
I18.t('subject').each { |item| title = item.title }
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: As you have it now, this would assign each `item.title` to the same variable `title` (rewriting the previous value).

Comment: Are you sure?! I just get an exception when I try to run this code...

Comment: Sorry, I mean *if* you could actually do what you are trying to do (loop through I18n locale strings under a given parent), the result (with the code you have here) would not be anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
I18.t('subject').map{ |key, value| value[:title] } #or value["title"] I can't recall
```

Comment: It is the symbol ```value[:title]``` at least for Rails 4.2